# AWS: Node.js Lambda function inside CloudFormation to upload file to DeviceFarm URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-device-farm

I would like to write Node.js Lambda function inside CloudFormation template that gets a file from S3 and upload it to DeviceFarm URL.

My code:

```
// get file from S3:
const zipTestsFile = await s3.getObject(params).promise().Body;

// 
let deviceFarmUploadParams = {
    name: "file.zip",
    type: "APPIUM_NODE_TEST_PACKAGE",
    projectArn: project.arn
};
let UPLOAD = await devicefarm.createUpload(deviceFarmUploadParams).promise().then(
    function(data){
        return data.upload;
    },
    function(error){
        console.error("Creating upload failed with error: ", error);
    }
);
let UPLOAD_ARN = UPLOAD.arn;
let UPLOAD_URL = UPLOAD.url;
```

How can I upload the file to device farm URL? 
I can only use Node.js Built-in Modules.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write a custom resource to call the Lambda function

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html